# How can I install the Raspberry Pi OS to an SD Card

Tags: linux, sd-card, raspberry-pi

**Questions**

Is there any way to burn the Raspbian OS to an SD card without the use of the [Win 32 Disk IMG](https://code.launchpad.net/win32-image-writer) application?

If the above is impossible, could I go about converting the file on my mac, then transferring it to my PC for burning?

**Background**

I am trying to install the [Official Raspberry Pi OS.](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/raspbian/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian.zip) I have both a mac and a PC, but my mac does not have an SD card reader and I do not own a dongle. So, the obvious choice is my PC... which I am not the admin of.

**Notes**

[Here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/quick-start-guide-v1.1.pdf) is the official tutorial.

I am using [Raspberry Pi Model B.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/RaspiModelB.png)

My SD card is 4 GB.

Comment: @gronostaj How would I go about converting the file on my mac, then transferring it to my PC for burning? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Raw drive access on Windows requires administrative privileges, so you won't be able to do it this way. But you can burn an Ubuntu CD or prepare bootable USB pendrive that will let you do it.